# Can't start docker container that can be executed on another machine

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have two the same machines

> Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09

in which I have same version of Docker

> Docker version 1.12.6, build 7392c3b/1.12.6

I run docker save on one machine and docker import on another.
Also I checked sha256sum on both machines.

And after I executing some kind of this command

```
docker run --name my_name  --rm=true -v /my_volume:my_volume image_name  /bin/bash
```

on one machine I get an error

> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"

I have only one hook. Size of container after import differs from original one.

Comment: Check your shells on both systems. `echo $0` or `echo $SHELL`. Are you using the same shell on both systems?

Comment: /bin/bash on both

Comment: I'd suggest to interactively connect to your container and try the command /bin/bash. Because the error message says it can't file it.

Comment: And whilst trying to execute /bin/bash inside of the container also check the $PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a notable difference, from what you said:

> I run docker save on one machine and docker import on another

Don't `import` the image, `load` it:

```
docker load < imagefile.tar
```

If you `import` instead, the image is imported without any metadata (WORKDIR, CMD, etc).

---

### `docker save` versus `docker export`

Explanation of the tricky concept:

`docker export <container-id>`: *Export a **container’s filesystem** as a tar archive*.
Therefore, `docker import` will just import the filesystem information as a new image, without any CMD, WORKDIR, etc.

`docker save`: *Save one or more **images** to a tar archive*.
Therefore, `docker load` will restore the complete image (filesystem + metadata as CMD, WORKDIR, etc)

The weird part is that you are able to mix and mess with them: save & import, and export & load.

So always: save & load; or export & import